# Facebook Exception #100 : Does not resolve to a valid user ID

Tags: facebook

While trying to post to a user's facebook wall using PHP, I am getting the error

```
{
    "error": {
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "message":"(#100) http:\/\/spats.in\/nssc2 does not resolve to a valid user ID"
    }
}
```

This is my code :

```
$apprequest_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/feed";
$mymessage="Hello World!";
$parameters = "?" . $access_token . "&message=" . urlencode($mymessage) . &id=".urlencode('http://spats.in/nssc2')."&method=post";
$myurl = $apprequest_url . $parameters;
$result = file_get_contents($myurl);
```

What is the problem?

Comment: er.. invalid user id passed in?

Comment: Your question would be *much* clearer if you formatted the code so it was more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. The request URL should have been http://graph.facebook.com/me/feeds/ and no id parameter was required.

Answer (score 1):

One reason for getting the `(#100) <url> does not resolve to a valid user ID` error is that the page has its Open Graph meta tags set incorrectly. You can use Facebook's [Open Graph Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to see what might be wrong.