# How to post to a news feed if a user has liked a page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Recently, I heard that, with the Facebook Open Graph API, [it is possible to post to a user's newsfeed if they have liked a page](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/465/).

I have been trying my best to follow along with the example, and have [created a dummy page](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3618086/test.html).

As far as I understand it, it is necessary to do the following:

1. Create the necessary Open Graph tags, including the one for your Facebook app

   - I've tested it using the [Open Graph Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdl.dropbox.com%2Fu%2F3618086%2Ftest.html)
2. Add a like button to the page
3. 'Like' the page
4. Obtain an access token (to post the message)

   ```
   curl -F grant_type=client_credentials -F client_id=MY_APP_ID -F client_secret=MY_APP_SECRET -F redirect_uri=https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
   ```
5. Post to the feed

   ```
   curl -F 'access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_STEP_4' -F 'message=Hello Likers' -F 'id=http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3618086/test.html' https://graph.facebook.com/feed
   ```

It's at this point that the message should be sent to anyone who liked the page. Instead, I get the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) http:\/\/dl.dropbox.com\/u\/3618086\/test.html does not resolve to a valid user ID",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code":100
    }
}
```

It's at this point that I'm confused. I've read through these related questions:

- [How do I publish to the group of people who liked a webpage or object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168434/how-do-i-publish-to-the-group-of-people-who-liked-a-webpage-or-object)
- [How do you programmatically publish to the Facebook feed associated with a 'liked' page?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3964199/how-do-you-programmatically-publish-to-the-facebook-feed-associated-with-a-like)
- [Facebook Exception #100 : Does not resolve to a valid user ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383617/facebook-exception-100-does-not-resolve-to-a-valid-user-id)
- [How to programmatically publish to a facebook feed for a liked webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419371/how-to-programmatically-publish-to-a-facebook-feed-for-a-liked-webpage)
- [Unable to publish to facebook feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060267/unable-to-publish-to-facebook-feed#comment13443132_8060267)

And have tried their suggestions, but nothing has been successful. What step am I missing?

*I can provide further details; I just didn't want the question to get too long.*

Comment: `redirect_uri` in step 4 should lead to your site, not to: `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token`

Comment: When I do that, the access token that I get back is the same.

Comment: The token you are receiving is an app access token instead of a user access token. Read here how to get the user token: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/

Comment: Can an app not post to a user's page? Or alternatively, can an app not post to its own page?

Comment: An app access token allows you to post on the app wall but not on a user wall.

Comment: Why is it then that I can't post to my own app page using an app access token (as above)?

Comment: Alright... that's getting me somewhere. Now I get this: `{"error":{"message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}`

Comment: replace `https://graph.facebook.com/feed` with `https://graph.facebook.com/<APP_ID>/feed`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, I figured out my problem. I'm including my solution below for the benefit of others.

The steps I've listed above are indeed correct, but there are a few things that warrant further explanation to avoid the pitfalls that I fell into.

## Posting to people who have liked an item on Facebook

### Step 1: Create a Facebook App

- You'll need to visit the [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) page and create a new application

  - You should not need a namespace, or webhosting for your application
- Fill out the details for your application

  - Primarily, you'll need to select "Website with Facebook Login". The *site URL* should be the same as where your site is hosted. In my example, I am hosting in my dropbox shared folder, so I used `http://dropbox.com`
  - Set your *App Domain* to the hostname of your site URL. In my case, this is `dropbox.com` which will allow Facebook to use `*.dropbox.com`. I also could have done `dl.dropbox.com` specifically.

### Step 2: Create the dummy page

It is very important that you create a dummy page. I found that most of my problems were caused by setting up the initial page wrong. If you create a dummy page, you can experiment (or at least create another dummy page) until everything is working.

- Make sure that your page is correct, especially the open graph tags. What does *correct* look like? You can [check out my dummy page](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3618086/test2.html), but I've included the `<HEAD>` below:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
  <html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
  <head>
      <title>Test</title>
      <link href="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3618086/test2.html" rel="canonical" />
      <meta property="fb:app_id" content="YOUR_APP_ID">

      <meta property="og:type" content="product">
      <meta property="og:title" content="PAGE TITLE" /> 
      <meta property="og:description" content="PAGE DESCRIPTION" /> 
      <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.stanford.edu/group/cardinalballet/Pictures/WebsitePics/portrait-placeholder.jpg">

      <meta property="og:site_name" content="SITE_NAME"/>
      <meta property="og:url" content="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3618086/test2.html">
  </head>
  ```

  - The critical piece of this are the `fb:app_id` (which should be your Facebook application id), and `og:type`. There are multiple `types`, and certain ones don't have publish permissions. For more information, visit the [Open Graph API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/). I initially *liked* my page when it was an article, which caused many of the problems that I had.
  - You can also check the page for Open Graph errors using the [Open Graph Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)
- Add the *like* button to the page, along with the Facebook SDK.

### Step 3: Like the page

The most straightforward part of the entire process. Visit your dummy page, and press the *Like* button.

### Step 4: Send a message

Assuming that you've done the previous steps correctly, the last bit should also be straightforward. I use `curl` in my example, but you should be able to get it using any sort of POST request.

- Obtain an access token.

  ```
  curl -F grant_type=client_credentials -F client_id=MY_APP_ID -F client_secret=MY_APP_SECRET -F redirect_uri=https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
  ```
- Obtain the id of your product page.

  ```
  curl -g https://graph.facebook.com/\?id\=PAGE_URL
  ```
- Post a message to all people who liked your product page.

  ```
  curl -F 'access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN' -F 'message=MESSAGE' -F 'id=ID_FROM_PREVIOUS_ACTION' https://graph.facebook.com/feed
  ```

### Step 5: Success!

At this point, hopefully everything has gone well. As the user who liked the page, check out their news feed. You should see a post with the title, image, and description that were on your page. Hooray.

...And that's how I solved it. Hopefully this will be valuable to other people. I would be glad to elaborate if I have missed any details.

Comment: So basically, we just need to post to the feed of the App. And the app actually have a feed.

Comment: I believe so. It looks like this information will be irrelevant as of November 7, 2012: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/migration/